# Получить значение переменной по имени Java

Tags: java

Кто знает какие способы получения значений переменной по её имени.

Например даны значения:

```
class Field{
    private static final long   MIN_FIELD_HOUR      = 0,
                                MIN_FIELD_MINUTE    = 0,
                                MIN_FIELD_SECOND    = 0,
                                MAX_FIELD_HOUR      = 23,
                                MAX_FIELD_MINUTE    = 59,
                                MAX_FIELD_SECOND    = 59;
}
```

Нужно получить значение переменной примерно так:

```
long getField(НАЗВАНИЕ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ);
```

Comment: map.put("MIN_FIELD_HOUR", MIN_FIELD_HOUR);

Comment: Если код НЕ ваш - рефлексия. Если код ВАШ - см. ответ выше или сделайте enum вместо класса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно записать в виде enum

```
    public enum Fields{
      MIN_FIELD_HOUR(0),
      MIN_FIELD_MINUTE(0),
      MIN_FIELD_SECOND(0),
      MAX_FIELD_HOUR(23),
      MAX_FIELD_MINUTE(59),
      MAX_FIELD_SECOND(59);

    private int val;
    Fields(int val){
      this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
}
```

Получать данные можно будет таким образом
`Fields.MIN_FIELD_HOUR.getVal();`

Comment: Вы забыли дописать конструктор. С пустым конструктором поле `val` останется нулём для всех.

Comment: Да согласен, спасибо. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Более-менее универсальный способ получения значения любого поля:

```
public static getFieldValue(Object object, String fieldName) {
     Class clazz = object.getClass();
     try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(object);
     } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;  //нет такого поля
     }
 }
```

Вызов: `getFieldValue(myClassObject, "MIN_FIELD_HOUR");`